# Cursor not visible with BackgroundColorSpan

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm using a `BackgroundColorSpan` to highlight certain text inside a `EditText`. The problem I'm having is that the cursor of the text field is not visible if the colour has 100% alpha and very hard to see with a lower alpha.

I've done some digging through the code of `EditText` and `Editor` (used to paint the text in `EditText`) and I've found that inside `Editor.onDraw(...)` the cursor is painted before the Layout (which in turn paints the text):

```
    if (highlight != null && selectionStart == selectionEnd && mCursorCount > 0) {
>>      drawCursor(canvas, cursorOffsetVertical);
        // Rely on the drawable entirely, do not draw the cursor line.
        // Has to be done after the IMM related code above which relies on the highlight.
        highlight = null;
    }

    if (mTextView.canHaveDisplayList() && canvas.isHardwareAccelerated()) {
        drawHardwareAccelerated(canvas, layout, highlight, highlightPaint,
                cursorOffsetVertical);
    } else {
>>      layout.draw(canvas, highlight, highlightPaint, cursorOffsetVertical);
    }
```

Does anybody know how can I reverse this behaviour? The only options I can think of at the moment are either to paint the cursor myself or to do some reflexion voodoo. Both seem a bit overkill.

---

**Update:**

I've created a bug report for this on the Android issue tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172001

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up doing is to create two extensions. One of EditText and another of `BackgroundColorSpan`.

The extension of `BackgroundColorSpan` simply doesn't change the background colour of the `TextPaint` in `updateDrawState()` but it allows external classes to access such colour.

The extension of EditText looks up for the special `BackgroundColorSpan` and paints the background manually inside `onDraw()` before calling the super implementation.

This gist shows the full solution (Imports need to be created):

https://gist.github.com/pablisco/d9dc57cc2e9dc85d24de

Note: It doesn't play well if the span is saved and restored (on rotation for instance) so may have to manipulate the spans when restored.

Comment: Is there some new about this feature? The link was deleted.